# How to work with an old angularJS 1.5.5 app

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm, angularjs-1.5

I have to work on an old AngularJS 1.5.5 app for maintenance purposes but I don't know how to setup a good env for it.

Which version of NodeJS/NPM should I install to make it working with the gulp tasks ?

Do I am also missing something required ?

Comment: Follow the official AngularJS guide to get started with setting up an environment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md

Answer (score 1):

first of all, check if the app uses npm *at all*.
apps from that era had other dependency managers like [bower](https://bower.io/) or even just a folder with a bunch of scripts.

second, figure out if there is a any module system applied or just all tags in the index. if there is a module system, it's [requireJS/commonsJS](https://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html) most likely.

if possible, just configure a virtual machine with software from that time, or even [use nvm to configure a older node](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) in case of npm being used.

if the app runs ok nowadays and there is the need of just little fixes, a special environment just for that would do the trick.

however i would recommend to ask for budget for a new app if someone asks for extend it with new features.

Comment: The app is using NPM for sure with a package.json and also writen in typescript (with typings). I don't see any module system, all are inclinded in the index.html

Which version of NodeJS do you recommend for Angular 1.5.5 ? I can setup a virtual machine but I don't really know what to install precisely.

I have a budget for later but I need to do some bug fixes for the production first.

Comment: typescript is an extra info. check the applied typescript version and look when it was released. then pick a node version from the same age with nvm. looks like you god a legacy but modern enough project! 
for reference, angular 1.5.5 is from 2018 but there is a 1.8.3 from 2022, consider an upgrade. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#183-ultimate-farewell-2022-04-07